# Modify a child record in before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

Struggling with modifying a child record in the before_save callback of it's parent.

Child record is `Photo` that has an attribute called `main` which is a boolean.

Parent record is `Deal` that `has_many :photos`

The form to modify the records is nested to make changes to a `deal` and users can also change attributes of a `photo` or add or remove `photos`.

Here's the rub.  I need to always have a `main` photo, and I planned to do this in a before_save callback, where I check for photos, and if there is no photo in the list for `main` I am setting main to true on the first photo in the list.

It's not saving the child record and I would expect it to.  I've added debugging statements so I can attest that the method is being called, I can also state the value of main is being marked as true... its just not being saved.  Am I misunderstanding this callback?  Light shed would be awesome.  Thanks guys!

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, allow_destroy: :true

  before_save :set_main_photo


  ### bunch of other unrelated stuff

  private
  def set_main_photo
    if self.photos
      if self.photos.main.nil?
        self.photos.first.main = true
      end
    end
  end   
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things going on here, but your main issue is that modifying a child in this fashion does not automatically save the record. You need to update your `set_main_photo` to call `.save` on the child record. While you're at it, a few other changes are prudent:

```
def set_main_photo
  if photos.any?
    unless photos.main.present?
      photos.first.update_attribute :main, true
    end
  end
end
```

With this done, you've now coupled `Deal` and `Photos` in an awkward way that has an attribute on `Photo` representing a condition of its relationship with `Deal`, and `Deal` managing that attribute. A better approach would be to create a new relationship to model this, keeping responsibility for the attribute entirely within `Deal`:

```
class Deal
  has_many :photos
  belongs_to :main_photo, class_name: 'Photo'
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :deal
end
```

This lets you simply set `deal.main_photo = deal.photos.first` and then `deal.save`.

Comment: The first example will only work if the Deal has already been persisted. It could be salvaged by using `assign_attribute` instead. But the later example is a better idea in the first place.